# VueJs with Vuetify not working in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, vue.js, vuetify.js

My app is working in in all browsers except IE 11. In IE I get `Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'`. I have added the babel polyfill, but I still get the same error, like the polyfill isn't compiling correctly.

I installed babel-polyfill `npm install --save babel-polyfill`.

I changed webpack.base.conf.js as below

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    babelPolyfill: 'babel-polyfill',
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
```

The project was started with Vuetify's webpack boilerplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. Adding the additional entry point as an array causes it to be part of the same dependency graph, and, therefore built into the same file. Now everything works fine, even in IE 11.

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js']
  },
```

Comment: Just a note that you may need more polyfills in case you want to target IE10 as well, see https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/463#issuecomment-352361055

Comment: Would this be put into the main.js file? and if so how?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
```

to main.js

I guess that it is not the best solution performance-wise because you load a module that you do not always need.
However this should solve your problem while waiting for a webpack wizard to pass by ;)